# Saying or expression about modesty

Tags: phrase-requests, popular-refrains, proverbs

I am looking for a saying or expression in English that is equivalent to "what is an ant that you want to make a meal from?" meaning that, I dont consider myself that important to make such a move, for example, write a book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would you call someone who makes no lasting impression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37377/what-would-you-call-someone-who-makes-no-lasting-impression) (a nobody, a nonentity, forgettable / unimpressive / unremarkable ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The OP is asking for a proverb or saying. The duplicate is tagged as a single word request.

Comment: [Look who thinks he’s Nothing!](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/jordan-peterson-look-who-thinks-hes-nothing/)

Comment: I’d guess OP is after something like: “That’s way above my paygrade”

Comment: @Justin 'Expressions' may be single words, so some allowable answers will be found there. 'He's a nobody' etc is a string.  I wanted to avoid (by pre-empting) the usual synonym-rehash bloat.